# Overriding a WSDL's "soap:address location" value?

Tags: soap, savon

Is it possible to override the "address location" value in a WSDL?  I need to supply a dynamic user/password within the URL.

This certainly doesn't work:

```
client = Savon::Client.new("example.wsdl")
client.http.url = "https://foo:bar@example.com"
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're actually just trying to change the URL, this worked for me:

```
client = Savon::Client.new("example.wsdl")
client.wsdl.endpoint = URI.parse "https://example.com"
```

In newer versions of `Savon` it can be provided via configuration option:

```
client = Savon::Client.new(wsdl: "example.wsdl",
                           endpoint: "https://example.com")
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's how to supply a dynamic user/pw:

client.http.auth.basic "username", "password"

Make sure to modify your "soap:address location" node value back to just "https://example.com".